# Stored procedure does not return a result when sending arabic word from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server where I send a word to it and returns all the results that will contain this word and I updated my entity model to get this stored.

It works fine for English words but for Arabic it does not return anything.

Procedure:

```
Create Procedure GetResults
    @searchKeyword nvarchar(50)
As
    select * 
    from products 
    where title like N'%' + @searchKeyword + '%'
```

C#:

```
public void GetResultsFunc(string keyword)
{
    var result = Context.GetResults(keyword);
}
```

Comment: Are there any results while executing your SQL code in SQL server? `select * 
    from products 
    where title like N'%arabic_word_goes_here%'`

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, yes the query returns results when i use the arabic word directly

Comment: And for `EXEC GetResults 'arabic_word'`, it works just fine?

Comment: only if i added N before it,
EXEC GetResults 'بطاقة'  does not work,
EXEC GetResults N'بطاقة'  works

Comment: What is the `title` column type?

Comment: its type is nvarchar(300)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think when the procedure was first mapped to entity the parameter was varchar
and then was changed to nvarchar.
i opened the edmx file as XML and found it mapped as varchar, changed it to nvarchar and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Then:

```
public void GetResultsFunc(string keyword)
{
    var result = Context.GetResults(DbFunctions.AsUnicode(keyword));
}
```

If that doesn't work, then this works:

```
var products = Context.Database.SqlQuery<Product>("EXEC GetResults @keyword", new SqlParameter("@keyword", "بطاقة")).ToList();
```

Comment: @a.tolba Check my answer.